# Use of unresolved identifier 'advance' swift3

Tags: swift

[image]

As far as I understood things(`advance()`) have changed in swift 3, but I don't manage to get it to work, whats the proper way to do it in swift 3?

```
        // Set the note text as the default post message.
        if (self.full_description.text?.characters.count)! <= 140 {
            twitterComposeVC?.setInitialText("\(self.full_description.text)")
        }
        else {
            let index = advance(self.noteTextview.text.startIndex, 140)
            let subText = self.noteTextview.text.substringToIndex(index)
            twitterComposeVC.setInitialText("\(subText)")
        }
```

Comment: @EricAya thank you, probably but I don't know how to apply it to my example, n00b inside

Comment: Yeah it's not a real duplicate you're right. Let's someone give you an answer specific to your case, then. Just wait a few minutes. :)

Comment: I'm a little confused by your code – why are you indexing `noteTextview.text` after checking that  `full_description.text?.characters.count > 140`? Also why are you using optional chaining on `twitterComposeVC` in one branch, but not the other (I don't see how that could compile)? Also why are you using string interpolation on a single string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated for Swift 4.x:**

You need to use the `String` method `index(_:offsetBy:)` to advance the index and replace the deprecated `substring(to:)` with a String slicing subscript with a 'partial range upto' operator:

```
let index = self.noteTextview.text.index(self.noteTextview.text.startIndex, offsetBy: 140)
let subText = String(self.noteTextview.text[..<index])
```

Another way to get the first 140 characters of your `String` would be:

```
let subText = String(self.noteTextview.text.prefix(140))
```